# Facebook post url image

Tags: facebook, image, url, social-networking

Just wondering what HTML5 element is shown as the image for a Facebook post which contains a preview of the URL mentioned in the post?

I want to post a link to my website and have my logo appear in the image box of the URL preview...

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: No, not clear what you are asking. What data FB pulls from your site, you can specify why Open Graph meta tags, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup But why it would be of interest for you to know what HTML(5) elements they use on their end, I can’t see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding Facebook specific OpenGraph meta tags in the header of your webpage.
Here are the meta tags you need to add

```
<meta property="og:url"                content="WEBSITE LINK" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="article" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="IT WILL APPEAR IN BIG FONTS" />
<meta property="og:description"        content="THIS WILL BE SUBTEXT" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="LINK OF THE IMAGE" />
```

you can check out meta tags in details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

Also to verify how it will look and what actually Facebook sees through meta tags you can go to the Open [Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=images.google.com)

Example shows what will be seen once you try to share https://images.google.com

Hope this is what you are looking for.